# Did Chopin request that his Prelude Op. 28 No. 4 (E minor) be played at his own funeral?

Tags: classical-music, history, chopin

I have read in a couple of places that Chopin himself requested for his Prelude Op. 28 No. 4 to be played at his own funeral, but no citation was given. Now I know that the preludes No. 4 and No. 6 were played at Chopin's funeral; but **did he actually *request* the Prelude No. 4 for his funeral?**

[Maurycy Karasowski says](https://archive.org/details/fredericchopinhi02kara/page/320) (bottom of p320, top of p321) that Chopin requested that the only music to be played at his funeral be the Mozart Requiem.

Comment: Can I ask: do you have a *reputable* source saying that Chopin requested the E minor prelude? I ask because it is often difficult to disprove a negative -- it's doubtful that a reliable source is going to go out of its way to say, "By the way, here's a list of all the thousands of pieces Chopin *didn't* request for his funeral." My initial cursory search concurs with you: it seems the Mozart Requiem was the main (perhaps only) item in Chopin's own plans.

Comment: @Athanasius No. I was hoping that if the claim is true, someone could give a source for it (and perhaps, if false, someone might know the origin of this "Chinese whisper"). Webages with the claim include: (1) Wikipedia [with no citation] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelude,_Op._28,_No._4_(Chopin); (2) https://www.pianostreet.com/chopin-sheet-music/preludes/prelude-op-28-4-e-minor.htm or https://www.lisamandel.net/2018/08/13/chopins-best-piano-pieces/; (3) https://www.mfiles.co.uk/scores/prelude04.htm; (4) https://www.onlinepianist.com/piano-songs/frederic-chopin/prelude-in-e-minor

Answer (score 2):

The original source for the Wikipedia entry is a *New York Times* article from 2003:

https://www.nytimes.com/2003/04/20/books/chapters/chopins-funeral.html

"Chopin had planned the musical program whose principal offering was to be a performance of Mozart's Requiem. [...] Shouldering the massive coffin, the six men moved up the nave to the sounds of the organ playing Chopin's Preludes in E Minor and B Minor."

Though [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelude,_Op._28,_No.*4*(Chopin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelude,_Op._28,_No._4_(Chopin)g/wiki/Preludes_(Chopin)) doesn't cite this explicitly, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preludes_(Chopin) provides the link.